# Active Directory LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN returns no records after OU move

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are seeing an odd issue with Active Directory LDAP querying.

The situation is: We have a security group in a given OU. That security group needs to move to a totally *different* OU.

We have an application that uses LDAP to authenticate against AD, and it queries using the Active Directory **[LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)**, so that it supports embedded groups:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SystemAdministrators,OU=SA Users,OU=System Administrators,OU=Departments,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com)
```

An example query would be:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -W -H 'ldap://ny-dc02.ds.example.com:389' -D '[binding account details]' -b 'OU=Departments,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com' '(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SystemAdministrators,OU=SA Users,OU=System Administrators,OU=Departments,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com)' dn
```

It returns a full list of users that belong to the requested OU - as expected.

However, if we move that group out of `Departments\System Administrators` and into `Security Groups\System Administration` (and update the query appropriately):

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SystemAdministrators,OU=System Administration,OU=Security Groups,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com)
```

for example:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -W -H 'ldap://ny-dc02.ds.example.com:389' -D '[binding account details]' -b 'OU=Security Groups,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com' '(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=SystemAdministrators,OU=System Administration,OU=Security Groups,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com)' dn
```

We get no results returned at all from LDAP Search.

Our first thought was "Oh, it's probably caching something". But we left the security group in its new OU for several hours and we still saw the same results.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any suggestions on where to troubleshoot next?

Comment: I'd check what is really queried / answered by sniffing the packets. Also: are the GUIDs (+ the rest of the AD attributes) updated in AD? Or are they staying the same? Are you able to query a newly created user in the new OU?

Comment: @Lenniey Packet capture confirms the request is as expected. Also, creating a new user and assigning them to that group does not show up in the query either (I can confirm that they show up if I remove the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` parameter though).

Comment: So, it works as expected without the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` parameter? Well...this is strange. Any differences in the query to the "old" OU besides the OU-name, of course?

Comment: @Lenniey correct. As for differences, I honestly couldn't say - they're very old OUs so there's potentially a few differences.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in my AD environment using: `C:\Windows\system32>ldifde -f t.txt -d "DC=example,DC=com" -r "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=testgroup,OU=Test,DC=example,DC=com)"` - everything worked as expected. Then I moved the group to another OU and re-ran the query and still everything was fine (e.g. no caching etc.). So I've got no clue for why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with `ldifde` on your DC?

Comment: Does removing the search base, or using `DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com`, make any difference?

Comment: was there any LDAP error code returned? First thing in my mind was that you probably have wrong DN in your query, but then you said it worked if removed the chain option. //// EDIT: so I google the usage of the chain option, noted that the search base is supposed to set to where the USER is located, rather than where the group is (location of group is included already in the option). So regardless where the group is, your search base should remain same (if user wasn't moved).

Comment: @Lenniey Same issue with ldifde, but see my next comment to jscott for more info

Comment: @jscott interestingly, this worked! It was very slow (because the entire domain was searched), but it returned the accounts as it should have. Likely related to what strongline said in his comment

Comment: @strongline you are absolutally correct! Changing the search base fixed the issue. Please post that as an answer so I can upvote it and pass it on to the application developers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search base is supposed to set to where the USER is located, rather than where the group is (location of group is included already in the option). So regardless where the group is, your search base should remain same (if user wasn't moved).

Comment: Hm. Maybe I'm wrong, but as I tested the AD query by moving the group (not the user/s or anything, just the group) my results were exactly the ones I would have expected, like @MarkHenderson. Or maybe the AD/DC included command just behaves differently.

Comment: @Lenniey my two OUs are disconnected from each other and thus the search base. Did the search base include both of the OUs you tested with?

Comment: @MarkHenderson Yeah, that's why I'm so confused :)

Answer (score 0):

What about permissions. Does the application have permission to search in the new OU?  I would look at the effective rights on the old and new OUs.

Also, i would confirm that the new location is actually an OU.  it is possible to create "Container" objects in AD, much like the "Users" container is not an OU.  As such the DN would change from:
CN=SystemAdministrators,OU=System Administration,OU=Security Groups,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com
to:
CN=SystemAdministrators,**CN=System Administration**,OU=Security Groups,DC=ds,DC=example,DC=com

Comment: Permissions were correct. The moment I changed the search root, the query worked exactly as it should. It looks like it was a bug in the application code that assumed the users would live in the same OU tree as the group.